# How to show that this limit exists?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, gamma-function

How to show that $$S =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}2)}{\Gamma(\frac n2)\sqrt{n}}$$ exists? If it exists I can show that is equal to $\displaystyle \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ [0], but I don't really know how to prove that it exists.

Thank you :)

[0] Since $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}2)}{\Gamma(\frac n2)\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\left(\frac n2 + \frac 12\right)\Gamma(\frac{n-1}2)}{\Gamma(\frac n2)\sqrt{n}} =\frac{\left(\frac n2 + \frac 12\right)\Gamma(\frac{n-1}2)\sqrt{n-1}}{\Gamma(\frac n2)\sqrt{n(n-1)}} $$

Taking limit yields $S = \frac 1{2S} \implies S = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Though [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) works fine, I hope there is a direct proof.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the subsequences $n_k=2k$ and $n_k=2k-1$ (there are formulas for $\Gamma(k)=(k-1)!$ and for $\Gamma(\frac{2k-1}{2})$, which I don't remember. If their limits are equal, it is an easy exercise in sequences to show that the whole series converges to that limit.

Comment: Letting $n=2p$, we are left to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma\bigg(p+\dfrac12\bigg)}{\Gamma \big(p\big)~\sqrt p}~=~1$, which is true, since, in general, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma\bigg(p+\dfrac1k\bigg)}{\Gamma \big(p\big)~\sqrt[\Large k]p}~=~1$.

Comment: @Lucian Wow that is come cool result! Can you provide some reference to the result and to it's proof? :-)

Comment: @EclipseSun Thanks, the stirling formula actually finds the limit without a problem. Let's wait for a direct proof though :-)

Comment: @Ant: Just imagine that instead of $\dfrac1k$ we have $m\in\mathbb N$, and prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma\bigg(p+m\bigg)}{\Gamma \big(p\big)~p^m}~=~1$.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a limit usually means that it exists. The trick to actually get a proof is to present your results slightly differently :

The first line of your computation does not involve limits, so you are allowed to write it without having proved that a limit exists. Now you should perform a few simplifications (which you have presumably done when taking the limits on the following line), *then* state that all the remaining factors have a limit and invoke the general theorems for limits to state that your whole expression has a limit. Which you have exhibited, if your computations are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I am left (without any actual simplification, just rearranging terms) with $\frac{n/2 + 1/2}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}2)\sqrt{n-1}}{\Gamma(\frac n2)}$ and I can only take the limits and write it as a product of limits if I know that $S$ exists, yielding $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 1S$

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not carefully enough your question.